# docker container with Nestjs app fail to start

Tags: docker, nestjs, docker-desktop

Hi I'm beginner with Docker

I use the Docker Desktop on Windows (Linux Containers) to manage containers and I need to create a container with a NestJs application.

I built the image containing the app but when I want to run a container with this image I get this error:

```
> helloworld@0.0.1 start /usr/src/app
> nest start
/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nest: line 1: ../@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! helloworld@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the helloworld@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-12T09_10_04_973Z-debug.log
```

my Dockerfile is like this

```
FROM node:current-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json 
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run start"]
```

With this dockerfile it's working on Linux but on Windows I get the error.
I tried to use nestjs official docker image instead of node but I get same error.

Comment: How are you running the container?  (A frequent Node setup seems to be to overwrite the image's `node_modules` directory with a volume, and that can lead to errors like this.)

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze I try to run the container with this command
docker run --name hello hello:1.0

Comment: What David's said is possible. Step COPY . . could override the node_modules installed with npm install in one step above